# Query MYSQL with a date in the format of 10-OCT-15

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I am trying to query a MYSQL database to return all records with today's date -

```
SELECT * 
FROM credit_application
created_on = '15-OCT-15';
```

But it's failing because of the 'OCT' part within the query. How can I resolve this please?

Comment: Just convert the date using DATE_FORMAT

Comment: use DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%b-%y')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql [**STR_TO_DATE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
SELECT * 
FROM credit_application
created_on = STR_TO_DATE('15-OCT-15', '%d-%b-%y');
```

Of course, this assumes your `created_on` field is just a `DATE`.  If it's actually a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, then you'll need to do a range query instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM credit_application
created_on >= STR_TO_DATE('15-OCT-15', '%d-%b-%y') AND
created_on < DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('15-OCT-15', '%d-%b-%y'), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

The other suggestions of using `DATE_FORMAT` would require the function to be applied to every row in the table, preventing use of any index you might have.  It would be a [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql **DATE_FORMAT** function

```
SELECT * 
FROM credit_application
DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%d-%b-%y') = '15-OCT-15';
```